# Authorization token in request header send null in web.api

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I send request in react app like this

```
const token = 'my_Token';
const config = {headers: {'Authorization' : token}};
axios.get(url, config);
```

But in server side in (web api app) :
request.Headers.Authorization is null.
How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes from `Authorization` and I think u will need the Bearer keyword as well. Try this

```
const config = {headers: {Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token}};
```

If the bearer keyword isn't required just remove it

```
const config = {headers: {Authorization : token}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS to allow any custom headers. Either you can use * or your customer header name like

```
EnableCorsAttribute("*", "Authorization", "*")
```

1. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
2. add following code to WebApiConfig.cs

   var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
   config.EnableCors(corsAttr);